# How do I take the text from a TextView and format it for USD Currency?

Tags: java, android, textview, currency, number-formatting

This is what I am doing -->

```
//get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
Integer value1 = Integer.parseInt(sand1.getText().toString());


//doing a calculation
Double calculatedValue1 = (9.5*value1);


//set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
result1.setText("$"+ calculatedValue1.toString());
```

result1 in the TextView looks like this now: `##.#`

I need it to look like `$##.##`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to something like this :

```
/get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
Integer value1 = Integer.parseInt(sand1.getText().toString());


//doing a calculation
Double calculatedValue1 = (9.5*value1);


//set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
result1.setText("$"+ String.format( "%.2f", calculatedValue1 ));
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Welcome :)

Comment: I am having a more complex problem and i a not sure how to ask it

Comment: you can come on chat if u want to

Comment: basically, i have the user the code you see above ten more times. the user then presses a button and a calculation is done. From there a subtotal and total are printed. When the user enters numbers into the edittexts the first time, presses the button, then scrolls back up to thange their imputs, then presses the calculate button again the app "stops working"

Comment: you will need to share the logs then i can say what is happening

Comment: i dont have enough reps to chat. I will aska new question

Comment: hehe :) it is night here.. if it is not answered by morning.. will surely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you could use this( Locale.US to format the number as USA standard and the %.2f for the decimal number) :

`String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", doubleValue);`

Comment: Awesome @Casey :D!